# How do you unit test a custom exception handler in php?

Tags: php, phpunit

Would you test a custom exception handler in php? For example I have the following:

```
<?php

namespace Freya\Exceptions;

/**
 * Custom exception handler.
 *
 * Instantiate with:
 *
 * <pre>
 *  new Freya\Exceptions\ExceptionHandler();
 * </pre>
 *
 * This is a dependency in the Freya-Loader package and is instantiated for you in the constructor of the auto loader.
 *
 * @package Freya\Exceptions
 */
class ExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * Set up the exception handler.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        set_exception_handler(array($this, 'exceptionHandler'));
    }

    /**
     * Create the exception handler.
     *
     * Start with the message that was produced. Then provide a stack trace.
     */
    public function exceptionHandler($exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<pre> ' . $exception->getTraceAsString() . ' </pre>';
    }
}
```

I would like to verify that when an exception is thrown the out put matches that of the `exceptionHandler` function. I am really unsure if I should even test this class.

**ideas?**

Comment: stuff a `throw 'Whatever'` somewhere?

Comment: That tests that an error gets thrown, what about the contents of that error, to make sure that theres a stack trace and the message is printed? or should I even bother testing this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can technically test your class by throwing an arbitrary exception and manually verifying the output.

Having automated, repeatable tests for the class would be done by passing a `new Exception();` to your `ExceptionHandler` class and verifying the output. You can test the constructor by calling `$lastHandler = set_exception_handler(null);` to verify that it the last set handler was your custom one.

From those two tests, you can rest assured that PHP has done its own unit tests to ensure that `set_exception_handler` works.